# count number of rows based on another table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - one for staff and another for their children.

How can I group people on number of children?

staff table

```
pID|name|family|ETC|  
---- |-------- |-------|-------|    
123 |abc|ddd   | 134 | f |   
124 |dfv |eee   | 900 | d |     
126 |rgt |wwww|750|m|
```

**children table**

```
pID|name|family|ETC|        
---- |-------- |-------|-------|    
123 |mah|ddd |2005/06/09|son |    
123 |dar|ddd |2013/11/01|girl|    
123 |sia|ddd |2003/01/01|girl|    
126 |naz|wwww|2007/25/01|girl|
```

**Expected table**

```
pID|no|        
----- |- |    
123 |3|    
124 |0|    
126 |1|
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join from `staff` to `children` and grouping by `pID` will do the job for you:

```
select
    S.pID,
    count(C.name) as no
from staff as S
    left outer join childern as C on C.pID = S.pID
group by S.pID
```

Comment: can get the number of staff based on Children Count? like 0 children 50 people, 1 child 60 people, etc?

Comment: @jaleel Why not? Just wrap the query into one more select grouping by `no` and counting `pID` - and you'll get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select S.pID,
(select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from children C where C.pID=S.pID)
from Staff S
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.pId
     , (select count(*) from [children] c where c.pId = s.pId)
  from [staff] s;
```

Replace [children] and [staff] with your actual table names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT staff.pid,count(*) FROM staff,children WHERE staff.pid=children.pid GROUP BY staff.pid;
```

This query will give you the resultant output.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of all PiDs (Even if they 0 children) then use:

```
select
  staff.pID,count(children.name) as count
from staff
  left outer join childern on childern.pID = staff.pID
group by S.pID
```

*(Same Answer as Andy Korneyev)*

However, if you just want the children count (who have greater than 0) then use:

```
select
  staff.pID,count(children.name) as count
from staff
  inner join childern on childern.pID = staff.pID
group by S.pID
```

Hope this helps.